# Spotify API responds with forbidden to my seek to position in currently playing track request

Tags: node.js, rest, spotify

For a small project I had in mind, I wanted to familiarize myself better with the Spotify API. Everything was going well until I wanted to try the [seek to position in currently playing track](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/player/seek-to-position-in-currently-playing-track/) request which only requires the *user-modify-playback-state* scope, when I send the request the server responds with **403 FORBIDDEN**.

```js
{ [WebapiError: Forbidden] name: 'WebapiError', message: 'Forbidden', statusCode: 403 }
```

It is worth mentioning that I'm using the [spotify-web-api-node](https://npmjs.com/package/spotify-web-api-node) module to communicate with the API but I tried sending the same request from Postman and the same problem occurred.

**I use this function to switch between users:**

```js
const switchToUser = (username, callback) => {
  User.findOne({ username: username })
    .then(user => {
      if (user !== null) {
        SpotifyApi.setRefreshToken(user.refreshToken);
        SpotifyApi.refreshAccessToken()
          .then(data => {
            SpotifyApi.setAccessToken(data.body["access_token"]);
            callback(); // Callback
          })
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
      } else {
        console.log("There's no user with that username in the database.");
      }
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

**My call:**

```js
switchToUser("stelrin", () => {
  SpotifyApi.seek(1569091982344).then(
    () => console.log("done"),
    err => console.log(err)
  );
});
```

**The authorization link:**

[https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=**{myClientId}**&response_type=code&redirect_uri=**{myRedirectUri}**&scope=user-modify-playback-state%20user-read-playback-state&state=stelrin](https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=**%7BmyClientId%7D**&response_type=code&redirect_uri=**%7BmyRedirectUrl%7D**&scope=user-modify-playback-state%20user-read-playback-state&state=stelrin)

**The seek function:**
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvMEa.png)

I tried looking up for the seek function in the [spotify-web-api-node docs](http://michaelthelin.se/spotify-web-api-node/) but I didn't find it.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a 403 when trying to playback without having premium but the message would say **PREMIUM_REQUIRED**, another possibility is that the parameters for Seek aren't correct, only **position_ms** and **device_id** are supported, with the latter being option, you could try checking what's being sent to Spotify to check the request to https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/seek is correct